# hygieia jira collector shows 401 unauthorized

Tags: jira, hygieia

I have installe hygieia components using the hygieia starter repo Here is the docker compose yaml link-https://github.com/hygieia/hygieia-starter-kit/blob/master/hygieia-starter-kit/Dockerfile

I have installed jira collector in one of my server, and it is throwing below error

Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized

Here is my application.properties

```
# Database Name
dbname=dashboarddb

# Database HostName - default is localhost
dbhost=XXX

# Database Port - default is 27017
dbport=27016

# MongoDB replicaset
dbreplicaset=[false if you are not using MongoDB replicaset]
dbhostport=[host1:port1,host2:port2,host3:port3]

# Database Username - default is blank
dbusername=dashboarduser

# Database Password - default is blank
dbpassword=dbpassword

# Logging File location
logging.file=./logs/jira.log

# PageSize - Expand contract this value depending on Jira implementation's
# default server timeout setting (You will likely receive a SocketTimeoutException)
feature.pageSize=100

# Delta change date that modulates the collector item task
# Occasionally, these values should be modified if database size is a concern
feature.deltaStartDate=2016-03-01T00:00:00.000000
feature.masterStartDate=2016-03-01T00:00:00.000000
feature.deltaCollectorItemStartDate=2016-03-01T00:00:00.000000

# Chron schedule: S M D M Y [Day of the Week]
feature.cron=0 * * * * *

# ST Query File Details - Required, but DO NOT MODIFY
feature.queryFolder=jiraapi-queries
feature.storyQuery=story
feature.epicQuery=epic

# JIRA CONNECTION DETAILS:
# Enterprise Proxy - ONLY INCLUDE IF YOU HAVE A PROXY
feature.jiraProxyUrl=http://proxy.com
feature.jiraProxyPort=9000
feature.jiraBaseUrl=https://XXX
feature.jiraQueryEndpoint=rest/api/2/
# For basic authentication, requires username:password as string in base64
# This command will make this for you:  echo -n username:password | base64

feature.jiraCredentials=XXXX

# OAuth is not fully implemented; please blank-out the OAuth values:

feature.jiraOauthAuthtoken=
feature.jiraOauthRefreshtoken=
feature.jiraOauthRedirecturi=
feature.jiraOauthExpiretime=

#############################################################################
# In Jira, general IssueType IDs are associated to various 'issue'
# attributes. However, there is one attribute which this collector's
# queries rely on that change between different instantiations of Jira.
# Please provide a string name reference to your instance's IssueType for
# the lowest level of Issues (for example, 'user story') specific to your Jira
# instance.  Note:  You can retrieve your instance's IssueType Name
# listings via the following URI:  https://[your-jira-domain-name]/rest/api/2/issuetype/
# Multiple comma-separated values can be specified.
#############################################################################
feature.jiraIssueTypeName=Bug

#############################################################################
# In Jira, your instance will have its own custom field created for 'sprint' or 'timebox' details,
# which includes a list of information.  This field allows you to specify that data field for your
# instance of Jira. Note: You can retrieve your instance's sprint data field name
# via the following URI, and look for a package name com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint;
# your custom field name describes the values in this field:
# https://[your-jira-domain-name]/rest/api/2/issue/[some-issue-name]
#############################################################################
feature.jiraBugDataFieldName=customfield_10201

#############################################################################
# In Jira, your instance will have its own custom field created for 'super story' or 'epic' back-end ID,
# which includes a list of information.  This field allows you to specify that data field for your instance
# of Jira.  Note:  You can retrieve your instance's epic ID field name via the following URI where your
# queried user story issue has a super issue (for example, epic) tied to it; your custom field name describes the
# epic value you expect to see, and is the only field that does this for a given issue:
# https://[your-jira-domain-name]/rest/api/2/issue/[some-issue-name]
#############################################################################
feature.jiraEpicIdFieldName=customfield_10002

#############################################################################
# In Jira, your instance will have its own custom field created for 'story points'
# This field allows you to specify that data field for your instance
# of Jira.  Note:  You can retrieve your instance's storypoints ID field name via the following URI where your
# queried user story issue has story points set on it; your custom field name describes the
# story points value you expect to see:
# https://[your-jira-domain-name]/rest/api/2/issue/[some-issue-name]
#############################################################################
feature.jiraStoryPointsFieldName=customfield_10003

#############################################################################
# In Jira, your instance will have its own custom field created for 'team'
# This field allows you to specify that data field for your instance
# of Jira.  Note:  You can retrieve your instance's team ID field name via the following URI where your
# queried user story issue has team set on it; your custom field name describes the
# team value you expect to see:
# https://[your-jira-domain-name]/rest/api/2/issue/[some-issue-name]
#############################################################################
feature.jiraTeamFieldName=

# Defines how to update features per board. If true then only update based on enabled collectorItems otherwise full update
feature.collectorItemOnlyUpdate=true

#Defines the maximum number of features allow per board. If limit is reach collection will not happen for given board
feature.maxNumberOfFeaturesPerBoard=1000

# Set this to true if you use boards as team
feature.jiraBoardAsTeam=false

#Defines the number of hours between each board/team and project data refresh
feature.refreshTeamAndProjectHours=3
```